# Admin Edit from - Show Image tag

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created a Grid and Edit form for admin. I can view other elements like textbox and selectbox in form. But now i need to show a preview of the uploaded image to the admin so that admin view it and approve the image. I don't want to add a image uploader just need to show a thumbnail preview of the image and on clicking that image it should open it in a popup window.

Here is the code i have used for the form.

```
class Buildnext_producteditrequest_Block_Adminhtml_Producteditrequest_Edit_Tab_Form 
      extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('producteditrequest_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Edit Request  ')));

        $productEditID = $this->getRequest()
                          ->getParam('id');

        $pdtEditDetails = Mage::getModel('producteditrequest/producteditrequest')->load($productEditID);        
        $sellerDetails = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($pdtEditDetails['seller_id']);
        $proudctDetails = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pdtEditDetails['product_id']);

        $roomBudget = array();
        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('room_budget')
        ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','ASC')
        ->groupByAttribute('room_budget');

        foreach($productCollection as $collection){
            $strRoomBudget = $collection->getAttributeText('room_budget');
            if($strRoomBudget){
                array_push($roomBudget,array('value'=>$collection->getRoomBudget(),
                                              'label'=>$strRoomBudget));
            }
        }

        $fieldset->addField('productcode', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Product Code'),
            'name'      => 'productCode',
             'readonly' => true,
            'value' => $pdtEditDetails['product_code'], 
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('productname', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Product'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'value' => $proudctDetails->getName(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('seller', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Seller'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'value' => $sellerDetails->getName(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('productbudget', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Product Budget'),
            'name'      => 'productbudget',
            'values'    => $roomBudget,
            'value'     => $pdtEditDetails['product_budget'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('shortdesc', 'editor', array(
            'name'      => 'shortdesc',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Short Description'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Short Description'),
            'style'     => 'width:98%; height:200px;',
            'wysiwyg'   => false,
            'required'  => true,
            'value' => $pdtEditDetails['short_desc']
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('desc', 'editor', array(
                'name'      => 'description',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Description'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Description'),
                'style'     => 'width:98%; height:200px;',
                'wysiwyg'   => false,
                'required'  => true,
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['description']
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('length_after_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Length After Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'length_after_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['length_after_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('width_after_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Width After Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'width_after_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['width_after_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('height_after_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Height After Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'height_after_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['height_after_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('height_without_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Height Without Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'height_without_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['height_without_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('length_without_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Length Without Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'length_without_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['length_without_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('width_without_packing', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Width Without Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'width_without_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['width_without_packing'],
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('quality_certificate', 'text', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('producteditrequest')->__('Width Without Packing'),
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly' => true,
                'name' => 'width_without_packing',
                'value' => $pdtEditDetails['width_without_packing'],
        ));

        /* print_r(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getProducteditrequestData());

        if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getProducteditrequestData() )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getProducteditrequestData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setProducteditrequestData(null);
        } elseif ( Mage::registry('producteditrequest_data') ) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('producteditrequest_data')->getData());
        } */
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show the image as below:

**Step 1 : Add Type**

```
$fieldset->addType('custom', 'Buildnext_producteditrequest_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Element_File');
```

**Step 2: Add Image View Code**

```
$fieldset->addField('product_image1', 'custom', array(
            'name'      => 'product_image1',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Buildnext_producteditrequest')->__('Image1'),
)); //product_image1 column name image
```

**Step 3: Change get Element Code in Buildnext_producteditrequest_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Element_File**

```
public function getElementHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
        $url = $this->_getUrl();

        if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'upload'.DS. $url; // path of image folder
        }

        $html = "<img width='100px' height='100px' src='".$url."' />"; // image html
    }else{ // image not uploaded show default image
        $url = 'no-image.jpg';
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'upload'.DS. $url;
        $html = "<img width='100px' height='100px' src='".$url."' />";
    }
    return $html;
}
```